# nodejs gm using imagemagick morphology

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, gm

I would like to use the command

> convert in.png -morphology Close Square out.jpg

with the [gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) module using the imagemagick subclass :

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });

gm(FILEPATH).morphology('...')...;
```

But this method does not seem to be defined.
I couldn't find any section about how to use undefined imagemagick functions ( custom commands ).

Did any of you guys successfully run a custom command with nodejs's gm module ?

Comment: GraphicsMagick is an old spin-off of Imagemagick and does not seem to keeping current with the changes made to Imagemagick.

Comment: Thanks, do you also have a proposal ?

Comment: I know little about GraphicsMagick. I suggest you simply use Imagemagick as it is more powerful and feature rich. Node.JS can use imagemagick can it not? It should just be an matter of configuration.